# $INC with $SET in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to do update a collection in mongodb that would work as a simple summarization.
Example: The average quantities by order, so every time an client order is created I update this collection.
My problem is when I'm trying to do a simple mean based on new fields values. Something like this:

```
db.test.update_one(
    {"year": 2021},
    {
        "$inc": { "quantity": 10, "orders": 1 },
        "set": {"mean_orders": { '$divide': [ '$quantity', '$orders' ] } }
    }
)
```

I'm using with Pymongo (mongo v4.2.8) and the message error is:

> The dollar ($) prefixed field '$divide' in 'mean_orders.$divide' is
> not valid for storage.

Any hints how to make this calculation AFTER the "$inc" that updates the data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a single step; you have to do it in two stages of an aggregation pipeline; note that `$inc` isn't an aggregation pipeline operator, so you have to use `$sum`; e.g.:

```
db.test.update_one(
{"year": 2021},
[
    {"$set": {"quantity": {'$sum': ['$quantity', 10]},
              "orders": {'$sum': ['$orders', 1]}}},
    {'$set': {"mean_orders": {'$divide': ['$quantity', '$orders']}}}
])
```